# What is the full lyrics of the song Si deus me relinquit?

Tags: black-butler

During the [1:42 of the song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcvO-1A4RHA#t=1m42s) there is some choir (priests?) singing in the background.
But I couldn't find out what they actually singing about.
Where can I found the lyrics of this song with the choir part included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to say

> Agnus Dei qui tollis peccata mundi
>
> (eng: Lamb of God, you who take away the sins of the world)

recalling [this other music](https://youtu.be/FMDo0QvujTU?t=13s).

Comment: I didn't understand how do you know it is exactly what its means?

Comment: It's translated at the end of the notes of the video I linked (moreover it is a very famous prayer... and I studied Latin in high school ;) )